# Ubuntu screen is small in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu at VMware. But I have a problem, and I do not know how to solve it.

When I have the virtual machine as a window, to can at the same time have access to my windows at my host operating system (Windows 8), Ubuntu vm has a very small desktop, and I cannot work at that. I mean if the VMware window is 1000*500 px, my ubuntu desktop may be 500*300, instead of 1000*500, and all the other space in the window is black. When I make the guest operating system full screen, then Ubuntu's desktop becomes normal and take the whole screen.

Do you know why is that, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you maximize the window, scaling takes over.  If you install vmware tools from the virtual-cd, you can have adaptive scaling or resolution changes from the guest OS.  You need the vmware tools installed to have that functionality.  On screen maximize forces host side scaling to kick in without guest tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I think vmware tools were installed automatically, when I first installed Ubuntu. Ok, thanks, I'll check it :)

Comment: It could have tried and failed.  VMware tools fail to build right on older and brand new versions because they can't seem to dynamically track kernel headers very well and keep the kernel module building.